# Calling method on object returns parameter string - Reflection C#

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, invoke

I am trying to use reflection to call a method on an object and there may be parameters involved. The code works perfectly when no parameters are specified but returns the wrong data when there are parameters.

Here is my code:

```
object temp = readerTask.GetType().GetProperty(bsplit[0]).GetValue(readerTask, null);

if (useParams)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = temp.GetType().GetMethod(bsplit[1].Split(new char[] { '(' })[0], new[] { typeof(string) });
    string p = bsplit[1].Split(new char[] { '(', ')' })[1];
    value = methodInfo.Invoke(temp, new[] { p });
}
else
{
    value = temp.GetType().GetMethod(bsplit[1]).Invoke(temp, null);
}
```

As an example, my input string is `Date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`.

The object temp has the correct date object in it that I want to format, but when I run through the code, the data in the value variable is `MMMM dd, yyyy`

How can I get the method to run and use the parameters correctly?

Comment: how is `Date defined`?

Comment: Are you sure that temp is a `DateTime` object?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @StephenReindl - Date is actually a string in an input form and I use the `Date` to grab a date time object that is contained within a different custom class.

Comment: @EugenePodskal - It's a `DateTime` object. I have tried calling a different method like `ToShortDateString()` and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is not `"MMMM dd, yyyy"`, but `"\"MMMM dd, yyyy\""`.

It can be easily checked with `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("\"MMMM dd, yyyy\""));` that prints exactly `"MMMM dd, yyyy"`

You should remove `'"'` symbols:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = temp.GetType().GetMethod(bsplit[1].Split(new char[] { '(' })[0], new[] { typeof(string) });
string p = bsplit[1].Split(new char[] { '(', ')' })[1];
if (p[0] = '"')
{
    p = p.Substring(1, p.Length - 2);
}
value = methodInfo.Invoke(temp, new[] { p });
```

Comment: That solved it. I didn't know the quotes were causing the problem. Thank you.